# getJSON and $.each giving me wrong values

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON object:

```
{
"pages": [
    {
        "id": "0",
        "title": "Some persons name | Author",
        "datatarget": "#navBarMain",
        "page": "imports/nav.html",
        "keywords": "some keywords go here"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Some persons name | Author",
        "datatarget": "#authorname",
        "page": "imports/about-author.html",
        "keywords": "some more keywords go here"
    }//,
   ... more elements could go here...

}
```

When I run the code below:

```
// JQUery Fancy Box
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Load Imports
    //Navigation
    $(function () {

        var divs = "scripts/json-objects/divIDs.json";
        var jqxhr = $.getJSON(divs, function (data) {
            //Attaching the events in the callback function of .load
        //Load the pages
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                $(key[val].datatarget).load(key[val].page, function () {
                    $('.navbar-nav .nav li a, .navbar-brand a, a[data-target]').click(function () { //This is what's not working
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $($(this).attr('data-target')).offset().top - 80
                        }, 500);

                    });
                });
            });

        }).done(function () {
            console.log("second success");
        }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
            var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
            console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
        }).always(function () {
            console.log("complete");
        });
    });
});
```

I get the following error in the console:

[image]

I've been racking my brain with this problem for a few hours.

What's happening is that the KEY is coming out as "pages" and the "val" is the actual array.

So I think somethings backwards in my logic

I'd like a second set of eyes, please.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop on `data.pages`, since that's what contains the array of objects and `$.each`'s callback arguments are `(key, value)`. `value` being `data.pages[key]`.

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON(divs, function(data) {
    $.each(data.pages, function(key, val) {
        $(val.datatarget).load(val.page, function() {
            $('.navbar-nav .nav li a, .navbar-brand a, a[data-target]').click(function() {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('data-target')).offset().top - 80
                }, 500);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That's the ticket, my friend. Thank you. I need to wait 7 min before accepting. Very cool. I didn't catch that.